# How to display images from varying directories

Tags: html

I have a website that can have images in varying directories. I'm
running Linux and some of the images can be in /tmp/ while others in a directory that isn't within the codebase's one. So for example, I have:

> /tmp/
>   /home/work/codebase/htmlfiles
>   /home/stuff/stuff/images

The code I'm using to try and access these directories is this:

```
 <img src="' + path + image + '">;
```

Where path is the directory and image is the filename. Path does end
 with /. Currently it will just give 404 errors even when I have
 confirmed that there is such a file in that directory.

Am I missing something? Does HTML not allow you to navigate from the
 root directory?

Comment: Need more of your code to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Your web server presents the files based from a web root directory.

So if your website is in /home/stuff/stuff the webserver does the following translation:

```
/index.html -> /home/stuff/stuff/index.html
/images/image1.png -> /home/stuff/stuff/image1.png
/tmp/ -> /home/stuff/stuff/tmp/
```

To do otherwise would be a massive security risk, allowing any online user to pull arbitrary files from your system.

There are a few possible solutions to this, what is best will depend on your situation.

You can map web paths to different paths on thy system
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

You can symlink the directories holding your images into the webroot. Ensure that you allow the webserver to follow symlinks.
https://superuser.com/questions/244245/how-do-i-get-apache-to-follow-symlinks

You can also hard link the files to exist in the webroot, you can use a serverside scripting language, or simply move the files.